# python combine dataframe data with same index

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame with an index(date) and a numerical column. It is currently in the below format

```
2022-01-01  52
2022-01-01  12
2022-01-02   5
2022-01-02  -3
2022-01-03  10
```

I want to combine all the data that has the same index date. The desired end result should be

```
2022-01-01  64
2022-01-02   2
2022-01-03  10
```

Comment: What is preventing you from even *attempting* to do this?

Comment: Not sure where to start. Everything I am reading is for combining two different data frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be that complicated

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03'], 
                'Values': [52, 12, 5, -3, 10]})

new_df = df.groupby(df['Dates']).sum()
```

This gives

```
2022-01-01      64
2022-01-02       2
2022-01-03      10
```